# Use a scope in a JOIN in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-9, scopes

I am trying to get all the products with active prices and display them and the active price using a scope in the *ProductPrices Model*. My *Products Model* has an hasMany relation with prices:

**Product.php** (Model)

```
public function prices () {
  return $this->hasMany(ProductsPrice::class);
}
```

My *Prices Model* has an scope is active that checks if the prices is active on this date:

**ProductsPrices.php** (Model)

```
public function scopeIsActive($query)
  {
    return $query->whereRaw(' timestampdiff(second, start_time, NOW()) >= 0')
                 ->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->whereRaw(' timestampdiff(second, end_time, NOW()) <= 0')
                       ->orWhereNull('end_time');
                  });
}
```

I tried many different ways to get products with an active price and display them both. Things I feel should work, but don't, are:

```
Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {
  return Product::join('products_prices', 'products.id', 'products_prices.product_id')
      ->prices->isActive()
      ->where('products.is_active', true)
      ->get();
});
```

I get the error:

> Property [prices] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

**or test2**

```
Route::get('/test2', function (Request $request) {
  $prices = DB::table('products_prices')->select('id');
  $product = Product::whereIn('id', $prices)->get();

  return $product->prices()->isActive()->get();
});
```

I get the error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::prices does not exist.

Why can't I access the ->prices() on my *Product Model*? Should I not use eloquent for this and go for the Query Builder of Laravel?

Comment: Why are you using `Product::join(...)` and not `Product::with('prices')`?

Comment: @ZoeEdwards thx for the reply. I can hardly find any documentation on this with() function. So If I use with() it will be with('prices')->isActive() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a combination of `with` and  `whereHas` might work:

```
$products = Product::with(['prices' => function($query) {
    $query->isActive(); // to fetch prices relation that is active
}])->whereHas('prices', function($query) {
    $query->isActive(); // this one is to filter the products that has active price
})->get();
```

Comment: AA cool I was already experimenting with whereHas() will check it now

Comment: There is some issue with the: "with('prices', function($query) {
    $query->isActive(); // to fetch prices relation that is active
})->" part. If I include it I get the error: "Method name must be a string"

Comment: yep i found the problem, see the answer again. i fixed the problem it should work now

Comment: This is awesome, This whole with() and has() is flashing in front of my eyes. Will look in to it but thanks it does it all!